# Zend_Db Update issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, sql-update, zend-db

Hey I have the below SQL:

```
UPDATE table_name`
SET opt_out = '1',
 opt_out_date = NOW(),
 admin_uid = '471',
 last_updated = now()
WHERE
    mem_uid = '7445093'
    AND opt_out = '0'
    AND verified = '0'
    AND reverted_credit_flag = '0'
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 1`
```

Which I want reflect in PHP...

```
 Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

$tableName = new Zend_Db_Table('table_name');

$data = array(
    'opt_out' => 1,
    'opt_out_date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
    'admin_uid' => $admin_id,
    'last_updated' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()')
);

$where = array(
    'mem_uid' => $mem_id,
    'opt_out' => '0',
    'verified' => '0',
    'reverted_credit_flag' => '0'
);

return $tableName ->update($data, $where);
```

It doesn't work and no error, just nothing...
The dump from $db is this...

class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql#149 (12) {
  protected $_pdoType =>
  string(5) "mysql"
  protected $_numericDataTypes =>
  array(16) {
    [0] =>
    int(0)
    [1] => etc...

Comment: Have you double checked your $mem_id ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just checked and both arguments are set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array notation:

```
$where = array(
    'mem_uid = ?' => $mem_id,
    'opt_out = ?' => '0',
    'verified = ?' => '0',
    'reverted_credit_flag = ?' => '0'
);
```

[Reference (Example #24)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.update)

Comment: Ah ofcourse silly me, I left the comparisons out, how is Zend going to now how they want to be compared...

That did the trick, thank you :)